# SSIS: FTP task - concurrent connections

Tags: sql-server, ssis, concurrency

I have created an SSIS package for downloading file from FTP server. When I debug the package, everything goes fine. But when I shedule the package as Job step, it sometimes fails to connect. The job is sheduled to repeat every hour and **in average every other run fails** with Error: 0xC002918F - The Login request was denied.

**The connection is anonymous and doesn't require password**

I have tested it for a few hours now and found out some info:

- When tested in FileZilla, I found out that the server denies second connection trying to download a file. Setting maximal number of concurrent connections to 1 got it working in FileZilla
- FTP command in command line works fine. Maybe because it closes connection after every successful command
- In FTP connection manager, I didn't found the option to limit number of connections

I have no possibility to see the settings of the FTP server.
What confuses me the most is the fact, that some sheduled tasks work fine and some fail. I haven't found any regularity in it.

**What I have tried so far:**

- Active/pasive mode
- Limiting retries in FTP connection manager to 1
- Shifting the shedule time, so it doesn't collide with any other (older) tasks trying to download from the server
- Setting the FTP task to ASCII mode (The server says to FileZilla, that it only accepts ASCII characters)

No luck so far. Still some attemps success and some not.

**EDIT:**

The FTP server is on Simatic device.

For this week, i kept shedule for every 1 hour and kept pinging the device every 30 seconds. Still some SSID attempts don't succeed and ping goes through every time :-/